# First author using delimiter and expansion

Tags: expansion, authblk

The following has a line that doesn't work when uncommented because I guess the output of the macro is not being parsed as a string. Is there a way around it? I still want to have a method that works generically on the `\AB@authlist` variable of `authblk`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\makeatletter
\def\getfirst#1,#2\relax{{#1}}

\def\ABfirstauthor{    
    %\getfirst \expandafter{\AB@authlist}\relax  % this line doesn't work if it is uncommented
    \getfirst First Author, Second Author, Third Author\relax
}
\makeatother        

\author{First Author}
\author{Second Author}
\author{Third Author}

\begin{document}

\ABfirstauthor

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best to hook into `\author` to obtain the author name in clean form so it can be retrieved at any time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\NewCommandCopy{\authblkauthor}{\author}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_bamberg_authors_seq
\RenewDocumentCommand{\author}{om}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_bamberg_authors_seq { #2 }
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 } { \authblkauthor{#2} } { \authblkauthor[#1]{#2} }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ABgetauthor}{m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \g_bamberg_authors_seq { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\author{First Author}
\author{Second Author}
\author{Third Author}

\begin{document}

\ABgetauthor{1}

\ABgetauthor{3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
 \makeatletter \show\AB@authlist \makeatother
```

you can see that the command has a rather complicated content which doesn't fit your idea of "First Author, Second Author".

It looks as if the authors are always between a `\Authfont` and a `\protect` so you could try to use a regex to extract the author:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\seq_new:N\l__john_tmpa_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \john_getfirst_authblk:n
 {
   \regex_extract_once:nnN 
    { \c{Authfont}([^\c{protect}]+)}
    {#1}\l__john_tmpa_seq
   \seq_item:Nn \l__john_tmpa_seq {2}  
 }
 
\newcommand\ABfirstauthor{%
    \exp_args:No \john_getfirst_authblk:n{\AB@authlist}
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\author{First Author}
\author{Second Author}
\author{Third Author}

\makeatletter \show\AB@authlist \makeatother

\begin{document}

\ABfirstauthor

\end{document}
```